# Exclamation mark used with assert method in its parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Okay this has been lingering in my head for quite a while now. 
In ruby on rails unit testing there is an exclamation mark with the assert method. Here is an example

```
test "No empty values to be inserted" do 
   product = Produce.new
   assert !product.save
end
```

Let me know the function of the exclamation mark. Quick replies appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

`!` is Logical negation.

- If product.save is truthy (that is, neither nil nor false), `!product.save` returns false.
- If product.save is falsy (that is, either nil or false), `!product.save` returns true.

Therefore, `assert !product.save` means that product.save must return falsy for the test to pass.

Comment: @Mladen Jablanović, Thank you.  Fixed.